# Writing a function for getting data from a URL

Tags: r, function, date, url

I'm trying to write the following function for getting Facebook data from a URL and then converting to a dataframe.

```
read_URL <- function(df_name,start_date,end_date,token){
  URL <-  fromJSON(paste0("https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/me?fields=posts.limit(30).until"start_date".since"end_date"&access_token=",token,""))
  df_name <- URL$posts$data
}
```

Unfortunately my function does not work, and i'm not sure why. 
Obviously the URL works before trying to convert into the function. 
This is the error that i'm getting:

```
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"read_URL <- function(df_name,start_date,end_date,token){
  URL <-  fromJSON(paste0("https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/me?fields=posts.limit(30).until"start_date"
>   df_name <- URL$posts$data
Error: object 'URL' not found
> }
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated 
    Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to construct the URL using paste. Try :

```
library(jsonlite)

read_URL <- function(df_name,start_date,end_date,token){
   URL <-  fromJSON(paste0('https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/me?fields=posts.limit(30).until', start_date, ".since", end_date, "&access_token=",token))
   df_name <- URL$posts$data
   return(df_name)
}
```

---

You can also look into `glue` package which makes constructing of URL with parameters simple.

```
read_URL <- function(df_name,start_date,end_date,token){
    URL <-  fromJSON(glue::glue('https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/me?fields=posts.limit(30).until{start_date}.since{end_date}&access_token={token}'))
    df_name <- URL$posts$data
    return(df_name)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak, also if you know how can i use this function in a for loop so i can increment the start date to the end by 15 days each iteration, and then add them to a table

Comment: You should ask this as a new question. Try to create dates using `seq` function and you can iterate over them using `lapply`.